# Patterns for waiting for a server side script to finish in flask. How to handle errors and premature termination

Tags: python, design-patterns, web-applications, flask

I'm writing a web app in flask that will be used to manipulate some data server side. Basically it accepts a path to a zip, decompresses it and places it in a temporary folder to be cleaned up later, asks you which folders in the zip to use and then runs a script over the files in that folder. This could take a long time for the script to run but I'm not sure how to communicate this to the user. I don't really want to use javascript, as I don't know any.

Also this process may fail. How do I communicate the failure back to the flask app and how can I make sure that if the python script does fail it cleans up after itself by deleting the uncompressed temporary files.

Are there any good patterns, examples or packages that handle such tasks in Flask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is the canonical answer to all "how do I manage long-running jobs in Python web apps" questions.

But it's going to be difficult to avoid Javascript. The basic idea is to offload the job to a separate process - ie Celery - and set a flag somewhere (probably in the database) when it's finished. But if you want your front end to know when that flag is set, it's probably going to have to do a repeated call to the back end to check the status: and that does mean Javascript.

If you use a library like jQuery though, it's only going to be a few lines. It's worth learning in any case.

Comment: Is it possible to use something like signals in the Flask package to avoid the javascript?

Comment: Not for notifying when the job is done, no. The point is you don't want to leave the browsing loading a page waiting for the job to finish, which is the reason for offloading it to Celery. So you do need JS to do that notification.

Comment: You don't absolutely need JavaScript - if you really hate it you can use either a 307 for your polling URL and release it every few seconds (terrible for throughput) or use the non-standard `Refresh` header to tell the browser to refresh the URL after a certain number of seconds.  But I am being pedantic ... JavaScript is the *sensible* answer. ;-)